# Binary classification of webpages where data in categories are very similar

Tags: machine-learning, classification

I am working on binary classification of webpages related to a topic of my interest. I want to classify whether the webpage belongs to a certain category or not. I have manually labelled dataset with 2 categories `positive` and `negative`. However, my concern here is when I look at bag-of-words from each of the categories, the features are very similar. The `positive` and `negative` webpages are indeed very close (content wise).

Some more info - the content is in English, we are also doing stopwords removal.

How can I go about this task? Is there a different approach that can be applied to this problem?
Thanks !

Comment: Can you think of any other feature that would set them apart? What were your personal criteria for putting them in each category? A learning algorithm may be able to "make do" with the narrow separation, but you're likely to have many false positives and negatives.

Comment: Thats what I am getting right now..a lot of false positives. The webpages were put into each category by experts, but mainly based on if they talk about a certain topic or not. In my case, the negative webpages are mostly forwarding pages to the positive webpages. I am currently digging deep to to find what else can separate the 2 categories.

Comment: Also I am scraping pages limited to the topic of my interest, this already limits the noise quite a bit

Comment: Ah, are you trying to sift out "blogspam"? You could try adding other features like article length, number of of ads on the page, number of links within the article, etc. I don't think you're going to get a concrete answer for this on StackOverflow unless you state your problem with more specifics.

Comment: @aganders3 Not "blogspam". Mostly websites related to scientific research. Some of the features you mentioned can be useful, anymore such features from your experience. Will try out. Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

You can use pairs of consecutive words instead of single words (bag of pairs of words). The hope is that pair of words may capture better the concept you 're after. Triplets of words could come next. The issue is that dimensionality goes really high (N^2). If you can't afford it an idea is use the hashing trick (check literature on random projections/hashing) on the pairs of words to bound the dimensionality.